# Deleting whole project in QGIS

Tags: qgis, delete, qgs

How do I delete the whole project in QGIS?

I used the above methods and was not successful.

Comment: Can you specify what you have tried so far and what do you mean with above methods? And what is your meaning of the whole project?

Comment: I have tried Project>save to>save project to geopackage;

Comment: whole project I mean, the project that I saved, and I want to remove it and start afresh

Answer (score 3):

If you saved your project in a GeoPackage, you can go to "Project --> Save to --> GeoPackage" and use the "Manage Projects --> Remove Project" button to delete it.

[image]

Comment: The "remove project drop down" is coming out dim, thus, is not available for selection